# Angular - Autocomplete Search doesn't work properly

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular2-observables

I am having trouble implementing a search box with autocomplete using Angular. In my search box the autocomplete shows the entire lists of contacts although from the console.log I can see that the filter is working correctly. I think this has to do with some problems related to observables but I am not sure where and what to change and I have been stuck for a while now.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.contactsForm = this.fb.group({
    userInput: null
  }); 
this.filteredContacts = this.contactsForm
  .get('userInput')
  .valueChanges
  .pipe(
    startWith(''),
    debounceTime(300),
    switchMap(value => {
      if (value !== '') {
        return this.search(value);
      } else {
        return of(null);
      }
    })
  );
}
```

This is my search function, from the console.log I can see that the filter works correctly but in the ngOnInit method gets the entire list of contacts and so in the autocomplete I get all the names.

```
search(value: string): Observable<Contact[]> {
    return this.apiService.getContacts().pipe(
      tap((contacts: Contact[]) => {
        contacts = contacts
          .map(contact => new Contact(contact._id, contact.type, 
contact.name, contact.address))
      .filter(contact => contact.name.includes(value))
    console.log({contacts})
    return contacts;
  })
);
}
```

Entire code available here: https://github.com/nicolagheza/gestionalino-frontend/tree/develop

Thanks for your time.
Nicola.

Comment: are you initializing the component on every keystroke? ngOnIt should not get called on each keystroke.

Comment: I am not initializing the component on every keystroke. I am just setting the pipe to the input form on value change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `tap` with `map` within your `search` method.

[`tap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap) simply allows you to do stuff with emitted values but doesn't change them in the process. [`map`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map) does, however.